# Android - Update current view dynamically

Tags: android

I'm currently doing my first Android Application and I want to update the current view according to some rules. The app is reading some sensor values, and the ideia is to update the screen to something like "It's all good!" or "Maybe there is a problem" with some images. My question is, should I define these elements in the xml of the view and toggle the visibility, or define different layouts and update the current one? What is the best practice in this case?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Depends on the effect you want to achieve. You should be good enough with a textview and changing its contents accordingly to the status read

Comment: @SomerandomITboy ok, thank you, helped a lot! :)